# Алгоритм оптимального размещения текстов вокруг круга?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой алгоритм нужно использовать для оптимального расположения текста вокруг круга? 
Чтобы он не налезал друг на друга, поместился в свободное пространство и располагался максимально близко к своей дольке?

Comment: Зависит то того в какой вы системе координат работаете. Лучше всего, если всётаки через угол - тогда просто круг большего радиуса, максимум по x y c координат отрезка, и два случая, текст слева и текст справа.

Comment: Начало координат в центре круга.

Comment: Я понял в чём беда... Текст наезжает... тогда нужно сделать массив прямоугольников, проверять на пересечения прямоугольники с текстом, и если пересекаются - спускать в низ нижний квадрат (с которым пересечение) и так пока будет пересечение.

Comment: Тогда пересечение может появиться с более нижним квадратом. И после перестановок текст рискует съехать с места где может быть ассоциирован с куском круга.

Comment: А как ещё можно? Ну.... можно тогда... разве что в случае пересечений увеличить радиус. В том же excel если не ошибаюсь, диаграмы сделаны 1-м способом. Надпись может болтаться не там чуть. По цветам - соиентируются;) Можно провести линию ещё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать что-то простое - например, выводить квадрант, начиная с горизонтальной подписи, и следя за последним занятым местом.

Пример на Delphi. Цимес в запоминании `oby` (old begin y).

```
var
  cx, cy, r, rr, i, bx, oby, by: Integer;
  an: Double;
  rc, oldr: TRect;
  text: string;
  size: Tsize;
begin
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  cx := 300;
  cy := 300;
  r := 200;
  rr := r + 20;
  Canvas.Ellipse(cx - r, cy - r, cx + r + 1, cy + r + 1);
  oby := cy;
  for i := 0 to 15 do begin
    text := Format('label angle %d', [i * 90 div 15]);
    size := Canvas.TextExtent(text);
    an := Pi / 2 * i / 15;
    if Random < 0.8 then begin //не все метки выводим

      bx := cx + Round(r * Cos(an));
      by := cy + Round(r * Sin(an));
      Canvas.MoveTo(bx, by);

      by := cy + Round(rr * Sin(an));
      if i > 0 then  //избавляемся от пересечения с последней меткой
        oby := Max(by, oby + size.cy);
      //подправляем x
      bx := cx + Round(rr * oby / by * Cos(an));

      Canvas.LineTo(bx, oby);

      //центровка надписи
      by := oby - size.cy div 2;
      rc := Rect(bx, by, bx + size.cx, by + size.cy);
      Canvas.TextRect(rc, text);
    end;
  end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]